# MySQL запрос с помощью php переменной.

Tags: экранирование, база-данных, php, запрос, mysql

Добрый день друзья.

Суть моего вопроса:
Каждый опытный программер не раз использовал в MySQL-запросе php-переменные- как их использовать- грех
спрашивать. Мой вопрос имеет к php-переменным в MySQL-запросе прямое отношение.

У нас есть 2 GET-переменных- tableDelete и deleteString. Несложно догадаться что в первой- имя таблицы, во второй искомая строка.

Если в БД найдена таблица с названием tableDelete, мы получаем структуру этой таблицы- ее поля, после чего во всех полях таблицы ищется deleteString, и если deleteString присутствует- удаляется запись в таблице(tableDelete).

Проблема в том, что переменная underQuery, содержащая данные, для поиска в записи БД, не работает в MySQL-запросе. Запрос оканичвается ничем.

При этом интересная особенность- если я вывожу наш болезненный underQuery(с помощью echo), и ввожу его вручную- запрос успешен!

Значит моя ошибка, скорее ввсего связана с экранированием, или какими либо ограничениями MySQL-запроса.
Просьба знающих ответить- в чем корень зла, где я допустил ошибку?

P.S- Повторюсь- в зеленом поле наш выведенный underQuery. Если его прямо ввести в MySQL-запрос- он отлично отрабатывает.

Заранее спасибо) !
Вот ссылка на скрин, "http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2014-01/20/a5rcf4gctfmo.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

subQuery обычно используют для обозначения подЗапроса.

У вас и правда неправильно оформлено экранирование.
Лучше сделайте так:

```
//Цикл
$underQuery[] = sprintf('%s LIKE \'\%%s\%\'',$rows[0],$_GET['deleteString']);
///цикл

$underQuery = implode(' OR ',$underQuery);
```

**N.B.
и просто совершенно обязательно используйте real_escape_string, иначе какую-нибудь какашку устроить будет очень легко.**

Comment: Спасибо дружище)
Век не забуду)
P.S- если кто вздумает использовать ответ knes-а- у него там пару ошибок, будьте внимательны.

Comment: эээээ... хоть бы написали какие.

Comment: смотри- \'\%%s\%\' поменял на \'%2$s\' - и все ок)
Еще раз спасибо брат)